# Android accessing activities from different package/application(folder in package explorer)

Tags: java, android

I have two packages(or application .I don't know what is it called as).I have a activity A in feed and another activity B in the sms.A activity should call activity B.I tried the answers present on the previous queries.It didn't work.Can anybody help please.

My package explorer looks like this

```html
    -feed
      -src
        -example.me.feed
          -A.java
      -res
         -activity_a.xml
      - Manifeft

-SMS
      -src
        -info.me.sms
          -B.java
      -res
         -b.xml
       -Manifeft
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code(first set *packageName* and *context*):

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
            //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is context(its showing cannot resolve)..??what is package name,is it example.me.feed or just feed. ? ?..and where should i put this ??inside the onclicklistner ???

Comment: You can set context=this; in oncreate function, packagename is shown in manifest "example.me.feed", you must use this in onclicklistener.